lightning-datatale Row Action's disabled attribute not re-render after value change?
I use a lightning-datatable component with below columns config:
isSubmitted
isEdit;
isView; 
targetCustomerColumns = [
    { label: "Account Number", fieldName: "accountNumber" },
    {
        type: "action",
        typeAttributes: {
            rowActions: [
                { label: "Delete", name: "delete", disabled: this.isView || this.isSubmitted }
            ]
        }
    }
];

The delete row action has a disabled condition: this.isView || this.isSubmitted.
But when this.isView or this.isSubmitted value change, the datatable does not re-render and does not re-evaluate this disabled condition, causing this disabled attribute to not work as expected.
I also try Dynamic Row-Level Actions, code below:
isSubmitted;
isEdit;
isView; 
targetCustomerColumns = [
    { label: "Account Number", fieldName: "accountNumber" },
    {
        type: "action",
        typeAttributes: {
            rowActions: this.getTargetCustomerRowActions
        }
    }
];

getTargetCustomerRowActions(row, doneCallback) {
    // This line output "undefined"
    console.log('this ->', this); 
    // This line report errors "Cannot read property of undefined"
    const actions = [{ label: "Delete", name: "delete", disabled: this.isView || this.isSubmitted }];
    doneCallback(actions);
}

With this method, I encountered an issue where this pointer is undefined. This resulted in the this.isView and this.isSubsmitted variables being inaccessible.Does anyone know why this is happening?
Is there a way to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

typeAttributes: {
    rowActions: [
        { label: "Delete", name: "delete", disabled: this.isView || this.isSubmitted }
    ]
}

This doesn't work since it's a static assignemt of disabled property. It's just evaluated once when targetCustomerColumns is initialized, so disabled will always keep the initial value.
Each time isView and isSubmitted are modified, you could create a new instance of targetCustomerColumns to reflect the changes, anyway I suggest to stick with Dynamic Row-Level Actions.
Since you're inside a Class, that code is always executed in strict mode and this has an impact about how functions handle this.
rowActions: this.getTargetCustomerRowActions here you're passing the reference to the function getTargetCustomerRowActions, so it's called without being accessed on anything (it's called by the lightning-datatable which holds no reference to your class). It's like having:
function something() {
  "use strict";
  return this;
}

console.log('this is:', something()); // this is: undefined

To keep this binded to your class instance, you could either use the bind() function or define rowActions as an arrow function, that automatically keeps the original value of this (the value that has in the original context).
Bind
typeAttributes: {
    rowActions: this.getTargetCustomerRowActions.bind(this)
}

Arrow function
typeAttributes: {
    rowActions: (row, doneCallback) => { this.getTargetCustomerRowActions(row, doneCallback) }
}


RubenDG, thank you very much! You have perfectly solved my problem!
